# $_SESSION that has been unset is saved back in magento with custom GTM (google tag manager) x GTM Weltpixel

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, php, javascript, google-tag-manager

I have some issue after add custom tag in GTM and setting configuration in magento by Weltpixel for GTM extension

so, i have custom tag for tracking event login, logout, banner click, brand click, etc in GTM for integration with Moengage.

all configuration is done and clear, can track these activity in GTM or Moengage, in my magento local site its can running perfectly, but different when deploy in staging site

actualy, for tracking these event i use `$_SESSION`

flow:

in observer set `$_SESSION['userLogin']`,
[image]

then in `default.phtml` I get `$_SESSION['userLogin']` and `unset($_SESSION['userLogin'])`
[image]

in layout, i add this code for default magento template
[image]

I checked, the result is:
when the .phtml track before the `unset($_SESSION['userLogin'])` has a session,
that's right after the `unset($_SESSION['userLogin'])` there is no session,

session history before unset with `var_dump` in `console.log`

```
array(11) {
  // other session
  ["userLogin"]=>
  &array(2) {
    array(2) {
      ["unique_id"]=>
      string(26) "name.examp@exp.com"
      ["name"]=>
      string(10) "name example"
    }
  }
}
```

session history after unset

```
array(11) {
  // other session
}
```

its true, right ?

**but,**
**when the page is reloaded again**
**in the `.phtml` track before `unset($_SESSION['userLogin'])` even there is a session again,**
**that's right after `unset($_SESSION['userLogin'])` there is no session anymore**

**and so on, sometimes the `$_SESSION['userLogin']` also disappears on its own**

GTM result, double track (example if use event logout)

[image]

when checked in the observer section using logger, maybe there is a process 2 times setting `$_SESSION['userLogin']`

but, apparently not, only 1 time

[image]

why can it happen like that ?
Can someone help me ? thank you

Comment: More than likely this is a FPC (full page cache) issue. To do something like this you would need to use the "Private content" and set various sessions. https://developer.adobe.com/commerce/php/development/cache/page/private-content/

Comment: Thanks for your answer, so the solution is just use private content ? Can't use session again ? But i have a question, why the session can be cached?

Comment: You will have to use a session to temporarily store and then pass it to private content.

Comment: yeah, thank you for your help, I have been I have solved it with private content, maybe this is the only way